# Can't upload filename with special character to google drive REST

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, google-drive-api

I'm getting error when I try to upload a file to google drive api with my web application and the file has an character with accent, like for example 'ç'.

I'm uploading the file with two requests, an initial request that has the file info and return the uri to where the file should be uploaded, and the subsequent request with the file itself.

**The error occurs in the first request** (the one with file information).

The error returned is just an '400 - bad request', and I have no idead how to upload the file with this kind of characteres.

Here is an example of request generated by my application when I try to upload an gif image file.

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Length: 257
Authorization: Bearer ******
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/gif
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 126
Expect: 100-continue
```

The request body contains only an json object with file data, heres the code example where this initial request is configured:

```
private WebRequest CreateInitialUploadRequest(String parentId, String title, String mimeType)
{
    String uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&access_token=" + AUTH_KEY;

    System.Net.WebRequest request = this.WebRequestFactory.CreateWebRequest(uri);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";            
    request.Headers.Add("X-Upload-Content-Length", length.ToString());
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", AUTH_KEY));
    request.Headers.Add("X-Upload-Content-Type", mimeType);

    //Setup parent id folder for file
    object[] parents = {new {id = parentId}};        

    object jsonObject = new
    {
        title = title,
        mimeType = mimeType,
        description = "foo bar",
        parents = parents
    };

    String strData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonObject);

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);

    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Close();

    return request;
}
```

When I try to call the method like this:

```
WebRequest initialRequest = CreateInitialUploadRequest("valid-parent-folder", "invalid file ç", "image/gif");

//I get an 'bad request' http error code 400 in the following line:
initialRequest.GetResponse();
```

Should I encode the request somehow?

Comment: Are you sure the character is causing the problem? have you tried uploading a file with, say a filename abc? 400 - bad request can be many things, though is quite often related to a security issue or the object your trying to post isn't correctly formatted.

Comment: I duplicated the file and removed the 'not english' character and it works

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? I know it's something about encoding (probably), but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I just posted an answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436002/google-drive-parse-error-when-uploading-file-with-special-unicode-characters/17449674#17449674. please let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the peleyal's commentary I solved my problem. I'm still using rest calls and not drive api, but I checked out the drive api source code and find out that they are using the HttpRequestMessage class. Changing my code from WebRequest to HttpRequestMessage solved the problem:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
string strData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonObject);

var content = new StringContent(strData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
request.Content = content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [Google APIs .NET client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/)? As you can see in our [Media page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Media) we support resumable media upload which is very easy to use, and will handle server errors for you.