# Upload stream for google drive

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8, google-drive-api

I Am creating application for WP 8.1 on C#, and using Google REST API. I want get upload byte stream from server for uploading on drive(without creating File), but I cant find API method who can get me this stream.
I looked assemblies in ReSharper and seen class Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload, this class uses for uploading byte stream, and has properties UploadUri, but this is private properties, and I cant use HttpWebRequest. Class has properties ContentStream { get; private set; }. And I cant set upload stream.

Comment: What do you mean with "uploading on drive (without creating File)"? what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want get uploading stream, File - it is class for build metadata for uploading stream. I can upload any file with using request.Upload(). But how I can get Stream for uploading with HttpWebRequest, without using standard REST-API method Upload();

Comment: I found this question[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431572/cant-upload-filename-with-special-character-to-google-drive-rest[link] but it doesn't work for me, and in this example man want upload filename, but not FileStream.